# git clone fails with 403 when running git server on windows

Tags: git, http-status-code-403, git-clone

I´ll try to set up a git server on windows by following the description in this tutorial

[git-server-on-windows](http://www.oudmaijer.com/2011/07/19/git-server-on-windows/)

But trying to clone the new, empty repository I get the following exception:

> error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing
>   http://myIP/NewTestRepo.git/info/refs
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

Are there maybe problems running the remote repository and the local repository on the same machine? Does anybody have an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: This is an HTTP server configuration problem, not a git problem

Comment: `403` means "Forbidden". You probably did something wrong with either the directory itself, or with the `Allow From`-directive, but without any of your configuration nobody can tell.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because the http server is looking for an empty file - git-daemon-export-ok.

1. Head to your repository, ensure it is bare, i.e when you run `dir`, it should look like

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x   4 fooo  admin  136 21 Dec 12:26 refs
   -rw-r--r--   1 fooo  admin  205 21 Dec 12:26 packed-refs
   drwxr-xr-x   4 fooo  admin  136 21 Dec 12:26 objects
   drwxr-xr-x   3 fooo  admin  102 21 Dec 12:26 info
   drwxr-xr-x  12 fooo  admin  408 21 Dec 12:26 hooks
   -rw-r--r--   1 fooo  admin   73 21 Dec 12:26 description
   -rw-r--r--   1 fooo  admin  161 21 Dec 12:26 config
   drwxr-xr-x   2 fooo  admin   68 21 Dec 12:26 branches
   -rw-r--r--   1 fooo  admin   23 21 Dec 12:26 HEAD
   ```

   If it does not, then do step 2
2. Run `git clone --bare /<Path to your repository>`
3. Create an empty file git-daemon-export-ok: `echo '' > git-daemon-export-ok` for Windows, just open notepad and save the empty file

Restart your server

Comment: thanks for your answers :D .. it was because of a wrong direcotry configuration of the httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem and it was because I had my http.proxy setting configured for my git client so accessing the local server wasn't working.  Running the following fixed it:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```